# Please ID this cactus species

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus

The label that was in the pot when I got it identified the genus as espostoa. Is it possible to tell what species it is? If not, does it even matter? I'm trying to figure out the name of the species so that I can look up information about it. Do all cacti in the espostoa genus require the same care, making the species name irrelevant (for learning about how to care of it)?

I am starting to doubt that it is even in the espostoa genus. All of those cacti seem to be fuzzy.

[image: Angle from the side]
[image: Angle from the top]

Comment: My first impression would be *Mammillaria*, but don't know which species. This genus contains [170](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammillaria) species...

Comment: @benn That would make more sense. Maybe the nursery put the wrong label in the pot. I remember the plant shop selling other cacti with the _Mammillaria_ label in the pots. Is it enough to know what genus a cactus is in to learn about how to care for it, or does the species make a difference?

Comment: Whether it is a *Mammillaria* or a *Espostoa* doesn't matter for how to take care of it. Like alephzero's answer already advises, treat it like a 'normal' cactus. A lot of sun and not so much water. For winter, however, I think 3 months is a bit risky seen the small size of the plant. I would say every month a little bit of water during winter.

Answer (score 2):

*Espostoa* species are mostly covered in greyish coloured hairs, except for one of two species when they are very young.

Whatever it is, it looks like a desert cactus, so it will do fine with as much direct sun as possible and free draining compost. Whatever that brown stuff is (some sort of moss?) get rid of it! Make sure the pot has drain holes, so it won't accumulate stagnant water at the bottom.

So long as they are not waterlogged cacti grow well with regular watering in summer (e.g. once a week or even twice a week in hot sunny weather) but give them no water at all for 3 months or more in winter to make them go dormant. That way you are more likely to get flowers than if you keep them watered and growing all the year round.

If you do get flowers, stop watering completely immediately after flowering until the flowers have dried up and fallen off. That may take a few weeks, even if the flowers are only open for 24 or 48 hours.

Repot it every one of two years at the end of its dormant period, depending how fast it grows.